# Mandatory fields based on other fields in the Zod

Tags: javascript, validation, schema, yup, zod

I have yup object schema validation like this (simplified):

So, let say I want make **barcode_old** mandatory if **is_change_part** value is **'Yes'**, and by default its opsional.

In yup, I can do it like this:

```js
const stringRequired = yup.string().required();

export const validation = yup.object().shape({
    serial_number: stringRequired,
    barcode_old: yup.string().when('is_change_part', {
         is: (isChangePart: string) => isChangePart === 'Yes',
         then: stringRequired,
    }),
    category: stringRequired,
    sub_category: stringRequired,
    is_change_part: stringRequired
)};
```

How do I convert it to Zod?

I'm still confused about how to do it in Zod, I've tried it like this, and it still doesn't work.

EDIT: I've found a way, but is there a better way?

```
const stringRequired = z.string().min(1);

export const Schema = z
  .object({
    serial_number: stringRequired,
    barcode_old: z.string().optional(),
    is_change_part: stringRequired,
    category: stringRequired,
    sub_category: stringRequired,
  })
  .superRefine((val) => { 
    // make barcode_old mandatory if is_change_part === 'Yes'
    
    /* 
      This can work now, but is there a more concise and better 
      way? I think this is too verbose, I should check undefined 
      and addIssue()
    */

    if (val.is_change_part === 'Ya' && val.barcode_old === undefined) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: 'custom',
        message: 'mandatory',
        path: ['barcode_old'],
      });
    }
  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar challenge and wanted to share the solution I came up with using the `discriminatedUnion`.

```js
export const Schema = z.object({
  serial_number: stringRequired,
  barcode_old: z.string().optional(),
  is_change_part: z.enum(["Yes", "No"]),
  category: stringRequired,
  sub_category: stringRequired,
});

export const union = z.discriminatedUnion("is_change_part", [
  z.object({
    is_change_part: z.literal("Yes"),
    barcode_old: stringRequired,
  }),
  z.object({
    is_change_part: z.literal("No"),
  })
]);
```

With this setup, you can easily define validation rules for fields that are conditionally required based on the value of `is_change_part`.

Comment: This also works, but now it creates separate variables, I want to wrap them inside one Schema like my existing schema validation in Yup or in Zod using superRefine(but this is verbose).